# XMLHttpRequest Level 2: Browsers

Tags: ajax, browser, xmlhttprequest, cross-browser, w3c

Is it possible nowadays? Are there any browser supporting XMLHttpRequest Level 2? I test it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

You can find a complete list of browsers that support XMLHttpRequest Level 2 here:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2

According to the site, about 62% of browsers support it, including:

- Firefox 4+
- Chrome 7+
- Safari 5+

IE8/9 supports the XDomainRequest object, but will support XmlHttpRequest Level 2 as of IE10.

Comment: Please note according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) you cannot use responseType in IE10+ from XHR2 spec.